# Add a non-scrolling view to a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to stop the user interacting with a tableview while I get some data.

So I can show and remove a view such that:

```
var dimmingView: UIView?
```

Is added and removed with:

```
func showLoading() {
    let dimmingView = UIView(frame: view.frame)
    dimmingView.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    view.addSubview(dimmingView)
    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .whiteLarge)
    activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    dimmingView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        activityIndicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dimmingView.centerXAnchor),
        activityIndicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dimmingView.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    self.dimmingView = dimmingView
}
```

And also

```
func removeLoading() {
    dimmingView?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

However, when added it moves along with the table (scrolls). If I stop the table scrolling when the new data is loaded it presents behind the UINavigationBar (the first cell at least). If I try to add to the navigationcontroller.view navigation.controller is nil (so I can't).

What is the best approach?

Comment: Add and remove it to/from window.rootViewController which blocks complete UI interaction or you can use third party library NVActivityIndicatorView too.

Comment: The solution could be, add contentOffset to tableview, add this animation view in the tableview's scrollview. After animation is complete remove the view and reset contentOffset

Comment: UIViewController has no member window...

Comment: Are you using `UITableViewController`? It would be better if you could attach a reproducible demo project link with your question.